# Maven can't solve vaadin dependencies

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, netbeans-8

I use NetBeans 8, working with Vaadin framework for a while, but today I've got this error:

```
    cd /Users/BlackSheepII/Sites/microapplicazione/sprint 2/microapplicazione2/microapplicazione2-ui; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" clean install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building microapplicazione2 - microapplicazione2-ui 0.2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for com.loop:microapplicazione2-widgetset:jar:0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.275s
Finished at: Tue Jan 27 23:15:06 CET 2015
Final Memory: 7M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project microapplicazione2-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.loop:microapplicazione2-ui:war:0.2: Failure to find com.loop:microapplicazione2-widgetset:jar:0.2 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've try to do a *mvn clean install* as suggested in another question but the error is the same.

I've try also to create project in all the possibile way (maven from bash, maven archetype from netbeans…). However, if I create a maven project with vaadin-archetype-clean, that is without custom add-ons as I've understood, all works.

I'm asking why and how I fix the problem. I think *maven* can't resolve a dependency and maybe something is missing from my **pom.xml**.

**edit 1**

Here's the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>as</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.loop</groupId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>as-ui</artifactId>
    <name>as-ui</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Versions for these are configured in the parent POM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>as-widgetset</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean validation implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- By attaching the classes to a separate JAR, we can import them
                        directly in the production overlay project, making it easier to compile a
                        separate widgetset for production mode. -->
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- TODO remove? -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven couldn't find dependency - **com.loop:microapplicazione2-widgetset:jar:0.2**, I think it's your artifact as well. You need to build it (this *as-widgetset* project, not the *microapplicazione2-ui*) first with *mvn clean install* (to add it to your local repo) or deploy to your Nexus (if you use it)

Look at your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>as-widgetset</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That's the dependency, I'm talking about. It couldn't be found in your local repo, you need to build it first

Comment: As you can read I've try to do so. But I've got the same error. Even with en empty vaadin example application.

Comment: you're building war project not jar. please add your pom.xml

Comment: I've edit the question with the pom file of the empty application that have the same problem

Comment: pay more attention to answer, please

Comment: Yes but I don't understand. Project don't want to build. And I'm very new both to netbeans and maven. On the eclipse ant just go on but we switched on netbeans now and I have to resolve.

Comment: so, you should have this project somewhere in your company, right? ask where it's located and build, follow my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a parent pom.xml which probably lists the other modules that need to be built/installed first.

Guessing here the locations, but try the following first:

```
cd /Users/BlackSheepII/Sites/microapplicazione/sprint2/microapplicazione2
mvn clean install
```

And then go to the UI project and try building that one.

Comment: Similar situation was successfully handled here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137684/why-when-i-run-a-project-created-with-maven-on-jetty-it-is-not-found-404/28141637#28141637

Answer (score 0):

Neither installing a local repository or make a clean install (that I've already try to do) could resolve the problem. Anyway I've try with a mac virtually identical to mine and it build and run an empty vaadin project. So I uninstall and re-install all again: maven, java. Something changes and I've got a compilation error. Then I bring the mac to support team, they brutally reset it and bring me a clean installation of mac os, so I try all again and it works (just jetty does not start but it is another story, and all projects run on tomcat well).
So probably something in classpath does not work properly. I'm afraid I'll never find out what it was. But it was a simple configuration issue. As I've understood, using maven you are not obliged to use a local repository.